# Filter ng-repeat by expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

With angular `ng-repeat`, how can I filter out items based on a key in an array of objects?

For example, I have this data set:

```
$scope.data = [
  {
    name: "Example",
    id: 1,
    status: "deleted"
  },
  {
    name: "Example",
    id: 1,
    status: "pending"
  },
  {
    name: "Example",
    id: 1,
    status: "active"
  }
  // etc
]
```

How can I remove the items with `status: "deleted"`?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
   <h1>{{item.name}}</div>
   <p>Status: {{item.status}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the expression

Comment: <div ng-repeat="item in data" ng-if="item.status!='deleted">

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can use filter in ng-repeat:-

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  
$scope.data = [
  {
    name: "Example",
    id: 1,
    status: "deleted"
  },
  {
    name: "Example",
    id: 1,
    status: "pending"
  },
  {
    name: "Example",
    id: 1,
    status: "active"
  }
  // etc
]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  
<div ng-repeat="item in data | filter:{ status : '!deleted'}">
   <h1>{{item.name}}</h1>
   <p>Status: {{item.status}}</p>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: That's because I upvoted... -1 + 1 = 0

Comment: @WilliamHampshire yeah i would also like to know the reason for downvote. :-)

Comment: @WilliamHampshire Now you will see a downvote. The reason for that is, it is a bad practice to answer a duplicate. Any basic question has a high probability that it has been asked previously. OP was unable to find it as he was unable to create a proper search query. But since you know the solution, you can form it. So you **should** look for such similar posts and mark them as duplicate.

Comment: @Rajesh thanx bro, but some of us don't have enough reputation to mark as duplicate ( i think 3000 repo is needed) so i answered the question instead.

Comment: @GauravSrivastava You can flag it as dupe. If not, you can comment its link and someone with right privilege can close it. Point is, you should look for similar post before answering. This will keep our portal clean and reduce duplication of content.

Answer (score 1):

use `ng-if` to check the status

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data" ng-if="item.status != 'deleted' ">
   <h1>{{item.name}}</div>
   <p>Status: {{item.status}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Should you not look for similar posts and mark it as duplicate?

Comment: Filtering the array, as the OP asked, is the preferred approach.

Answer (score -1):

You can add an ng-if in the div like

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data" ng-if="item.status!='deleted'">
   <h1>{{item.name}}</div>
   <p>Status: {{item.status}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not answer a duplicate question. Search for similar post and post its link as comment or close(*when you have that privilege*).

Comment: Filtering the array, as the OP asked, is the preferred approach.